# I could not understand which Qt version I am using

Tags: qt

So when I click Help -> About Qt Creator I have a such message.
Why in heading says 4.11.1 but below I see that Based on Qt 5.14.1

[image]

Comment: One is the version of the editor, the other the version of the toolkit used. It kind of says so. The Qt version that the editor is using is the Qt version it says it's based on.

Comment: Neither of those is the version of your Qt installation. Under the Qt installation folder there is a sub-folder with the version as a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is which version is used to build Qt Creator... You should check from the maintenance tool for your installed version!